# How to convert a binary array into one single variable?

Tags: c, for-loop, binary

I have an binary array and i am trying to convert this into a single variable so that i can read the binary bitwise consecutively. I have tried looping over the array and adding each of them into a variable but this has not work. Can anyone give me some pointers into how to do this?

This is what i have tried:

```
    char* filename = vargs[1];
    BYTE buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    FILE *file_ptr = fopen(filename,"rb");

    fseek(file_ptr, 0, SEEK_END); 
    size_t file_length = ftell(file_ptr);
    rewind(file_ptr);  

    fread(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), BUFFER_SIZE, file_ptr);

    char binaryLine = '\0';

    for (int i = 0; i > file_length; i++)
    {
        binaryLine += buffer[i];
        printf("%d ", (int)buffer[i]);
    }
```

Comment: *"This is what i have tried:"* - and its wrong *how* exactly? Specificity is important. Your question should include what you hope to accomplish, what is actually happening, etc. And the term "binary array" is either being misused, misunderstood, or both. What is actually in the file you're reading? And what did you hope this code would produce? All of that  belongs [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49829409/edit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there is some miss understanding, but when you read a file in a char* or char[], that is one variable.
Maybe try below code, and see what your missing.

Pay attention to, just to name a few:

- `for` instruction, need to be true to continue
- `fread` you need to get the amount of bytes read to loop it
- `main`, it's a function or it's main, show it
- `fopen` etc, would also neeed you to check for errors, which might help you to figure out why something does not work

regarding your question, It's important to ask a question and provide info, as stated in other comment, what do you want....

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

   const char* filename = argv[1];
   char * buffer=NULL;

   FILE *file_ptr = fopen(filename,"rb");

   if (! file_ptr) return 1;

   fseek(file_ptr, 0, SEEK_END);
   size_t file_length = ftell(file_ptr);
   rewind(file_ptr);

   if (file_length!=0)
      buffer=calloc(1,file_length);
   if (buffer)
   {
      size_t bytes_read=fread(buffer, 1, file_length, file_ptr);
      for (int i = 0; i < bytes_read; i++)
      {
         printf("%d ", (int)buffer[i]);
      }
      free(buffer);
      buffer=NULL;
      return 0;
   }
   return 1;
}
```